# How to solve Only secure origins are allowed

Tags: android, angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using cordova geolocation plugin in Ionic app . 
when i ran the app inside emulator i found this bug **Only secure origins are allowed** .
hence was unable to get the geolocation of inside emulator .
but using locahost it works fine probably localhost comes under secure origin.

browser im using is chrome. 
plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/

Comment: Is there a stacktrace? If so, add it and any relevant code

Comment: Please consider not using both _angular_ and _angularjs tags_. _Angular_ tag is for Angular 2+, while _angularjs_ is for Angular 1.x. Hope this makes sense. Which Angular version do you use?

Answer (score 4):

there is an issue opened for this problem
https://github.com/ionic-team/ng-cordova/issues/1413

Accessing the user's location is deprecated with unsecure (HTTP) context. See https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features.

Running your dev server on localhost instead should work.

Comment: Hi @Danilo , how do you run you dev server on localhost ? Thank you

Comment: @DonFabiolas There is no way to do this and run your app in an emulator, since localhost will reference the emulator instead of your dev server. If you just want to test in a browser, you can do: `ionic serve --address localhost`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the default web view scheme for Android is: http://localhost
The geolocation plugin does not accept "http://..." as origin for position requests.
On iOS it works because the default scheme is ionic://localhost

Set the Android Scheme to "https" in the config.xml file:

```
<preference name="Scheme" value="https" />
```

NB: it is necessary to allow also the navigation for the new scheme:

```
<allow-navigation href="https://*"/>
```

Other web view configurations:
https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview

Comment: That solved my problem on android, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For private IP address access, the latest Firefox seems to work out of the box (version 47.0 and above). If it does not work, go to about:config and set the media.navigator.permission.disabled to false. It's work for android too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using NuxtJS(Vue2). I use http://192.168.50.48:3000 as a host. Instead of using this, I build with http://localhost:3000. It works just fine now. Switching it back to localhost, and it starts to work.